# How to escape the special character in an ldap query?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I have one user on LDAP named with base DN

```
=CN=abc def\, ghi,CN=jkl,DC=mno,DC=pqr
```

and password is `xyz`.

I want to search this user in ldap, how do I do that? One thing is clear, the LDAP query should be like,

```
CN=abc def\\\, ghi\,CN=jkl\,DC=mno\,DC=pqr,xyz
```

tried these solutions

```
.getBindUserDN().replaceAll("[,]", "\\\\\\,").getBindUserDN().replaceAll(",", "\\,")
```

etc. What should be the logic here?

Comment: What needs to be escaped depends on the context you are using it in. How are you using this value?

Comment: I am specifying this value and searching for CN=abc def\, in the MS-AD. but it always says that user not found.

Comment: How are you "specifying this value and searching"? Can you show that code?

Comment: Sorry the code is not allowed to be displayed but I found the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution but it's very much specific to this case where we specify only one backslash `\` and a comma `,` i.e. `\,`

The problem was that, when I was trying to search for a ldap entry, I was taking the value of `Bind DN` directly. Later after trial and error method I understood that when I am searching for it's secret key we need 6 number of backslashes i.e. `\\\\\\` to find it's secret key as LDAP store it with 3 backslashes and comma `\\\,`.

But when I am going to look into Ldap for this secret key, so now I need to search with this new secret key, it means 6 backslashes should be there. So I have to search it with double the number of these backslashes i.e 12 `\\\\\\\\\\\\`

`PS:- This Solution appltes to a very particular case. But Logic should be similar if someone needs to apply it in a different way`

Comment: I have never seen any case that requires more than 2 backslashes (one to escape the comma in the DN and another to escape that one in code). I have no idea what you're doing, but there is almost certainly a better way to do it.

Comment: See, if you create a user in MS-AD as `Abc\, xyz` then MS-AD stores it as `Abc\\\, xyz` so when I have to do the lookup in LDAP directory for it's secret key, I have to serach it with keyAlias of `Abc\\\, xyz`.

Comment: I know if the CN has `,` it stores it as `\,` in the DN. But are you saying you actually have `\,` in the CN? Why?

Comment: because MS-AD doesn't allow to use single comma as it's a reserved character. To escape the comma Microsoft advises to use `\,`

Comment: We use a single comma in the CN (and I mean the `cn` attribute) all the time, and AD automatically puts `\,` in the DN.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-work-with-a-cn-that-has-a-comma-in-it/  If you go to this link

Comment: That perfectly demonstrates my point :) Notice this: "So what’s the problem here? Well, it’s not with the user’s CN; **Myer, Ken** is perfectly valid." A comma in the CN is perfectly fine, and no escaping is needed *in the CN*. In the DN, only one slash is needed to escape the comma, since commas have special meanings in DNs. There is no reason to need 12 commas in the DN.

Comment: yes. I think we were talking about the same thing. I have one person who uses `\,` in CN as well as DN. That's why I needed to find a work around for this very specific situation. :)